# Непонятен цикл for i in range(2,a):

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

Объясните пожалуйста как работает эта программа? Особенно то, почему i в `for i in range(2,a):` выводит

> 2 3 4 2 3 4 5 6 2 3

если ввести число 5? Ествественно при вводе другого числа, будет выведено больше или меньше чисел, в зависимости от числа.

```
from math import *

n = input("Введите диапазон:- ")
p = [2, 3]
count = 2
a = 5
while (count < int (n)):
    b=0
    for i in range(2,a):
        print (i)
        if ( i <= a):
            if (a % i == 0):
                print("a neprost",a)
                b = 1
            else:
                pass
    if (b == 1):
        print("a prost",a)
        p = p + [a]
    count = count + 1
    a = a + 2
print (p)
```

Comment: выполните ее по шагам в отладчике

Comment: Я не знаю почему, но у меня не работает эта функция. У меня просто запускается код и выполняется после ввода числа. F8, F10, Shift + F8 пробовал.

Comment: у вас IDE какая? ну и еще на первых этапах хорошо себя показывает отладка через print

Comment: еще полезно просто на бумажке "повыполнять" программу, рассчитывая значения ваших переменных. Обычно после нескольких раз вы привыкните и будите неплохо справлятся

Comment: VS 17. Добавил print после **if ( i <= a):** и получил результат, который не особо много ясности вводит. 

2
2 5
3
3 5
4
4 5
2
2 7
3
3 7
4
4 7
5
5 7
6
6 7
2
2 9
3
3 9
a neprost 9

Comment: потому что надо добавить не просто принт, а хоть с минимальным описанием шагов. Чтобы понимать, откуда он вывел. А еще лучше, "позапускать на бумажке". Если вы в дальнейшем планируете заниматься программированием, навык разбираться в работе кода вам все равно поможет. На мой взгляд вы приложили очень мало усилий, чтобы понять это самостоятельно )

Answer (score 1):

Цикл `for` запускается первый раз для интервала `2-а (а=5)` (то и `print(i)` = `2, 3, 4`), 
после прохождения цикла по интервалу вы увеличиваете

`count = count + 1 (2 +1)`

`а=а+2 (а = 5+2)`

Теперь в цикле `while` выполняется условие `count < n` (которое вы ввели), 
то цикл for запускается повторно,
но уже для интервала `2-a (a = 7)` и получается что `print(i) = 2, 3, 4, 5, 6`

если условие while выполнится еще раз, то вы получите что `print(i) = 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8`

Comment: Да, спасибо. Но я наверное несовсем правильно задал вопрос. Хотя и ваш ответ тоже помог с некоторыми неясностями. Я не могу понять почему for сразу выводит 2 5, 3 5, 4 5 и только после этого увеличивается count и a? Почему не выводит 5 5? Как я представляю себе работу этого цикла (буду писать сокращённо): 

i = 2:5
if ( i <= a):
if (a % i == 0): (не выполняется)
дальше выполняется увеличение count и a
После этого запускается снова цикл for
Примерно так я себе представляю работу этого цикла. Но почему count запускается только после вывода 2 5, 3 5, 4 5? И опять же, почему не выводит 5 5?

Comment: Я разделял написанное отступами для удобства чтения, но оказывается тут так нельзя

Comment: Я потестировал range и понял почему он мне сразу выводит 2 3, 3 5, 4 5. Но почему range не выводит 5 5? Это особенность функции?

Comment: И ещё вопрос. Если написать for i in range (1, 3) и вывести это, то ответом будет 1 2. Как тогда выполняется if (a % i == 0): ? Он ведь не выводит 5 5. Где хранится цифра 5?